# convert url parameter string with backslash, forward slash, and spaces to %5C, %2F, and %20 with encodeURIComponent javascript

Tags: javascript, uri, encode

I have a url parameter that needs to be encoded in a very specific way.

Spaces should be converted to %20

Backslash should be converted to %5C

Forward slash should be converted to %2F

How would I do this in javascript?

input:

```
var before_encode = 'MS EXCEL \ MACRO/AUTOMATION'
```

expected output:

```
var after_encode = 'MS%20EXCEL%20%5C%20MACRO%2FAUTOMATION'
```

The var after_encode will then be fed to a json get request and only works if encoded this way. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am new to java script.

Comment: replace? str = str.replace(' ', '%20')? And for each letters

Comment: ahhh... maybe our own customer encoder?  I think that will work!  How would I do this with the forward slash and backslash though?  Could you write an example of the syntax?

Answer (score 2):

it's my decide:

```js
const input = 'MS EXCEL \\ MACRO/AUTOMATION';
const output = input
  .replace(/ /g, "%20")
  .replace(/\\/g, "%5")
  .replace(/\//g, "%2F");

console.log(input);
console.log(output);
```

Backslash must be '\\', because '\' is a spec letter in programming

Comment: one issue with this answer otherwise everything works great.  I have a single backslash I am trying to change and not a double backslash like in your example.  Can you please change the const input to 'MS EXCEL \ MACRO/AUTOMATION' like what I had in the question and update the answer accordingly?

Comment: how do I convert my \ into \\?  The examples I have found online do not work.

Comment: @acodejdatam '\' - it's a special letter, this letter using with other letters, if u want use this letter for text - use double letter for get single letter, \\ => \, \\\\ => \\. Single backslash in code it's a special letter, but when u got this letter from other sources, u got as '\\', example: user write next string in input: "I like\love pizza", when you'll parse it in your code, you'ill get:    text[i] === '\\' -> true when 'i' == 6 and u'll get error because '\' it's a special letter